# Pass information in the same page without a form

Tags: jquery

Can I have a div where people could write and in the same page a non editable div with the same text? How to do that without clicking any button?

I could use jQuery.

I have the example here:http://jsfiddle.net/bJvQL/1/

CSS:

```
#input, #out { 
  width:400px; height:200px;
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="input" contenteditable="true"> </div>
<div id="out"> </div>
```

Comment: This would be purely JavaScript, so you should not use PHP.

Comment: Why the negative point?. If I know why I can fix it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#in').on('keydown', function () {
        $('#out').html($('#in').html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Ops. I don't know what's happened. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with jQuery.

```
/** Don't forget to include jQuery, and open <script> tags */
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#input').keyup(function(){
         $('#out').html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Also, you seem to be confusing client side scripting (JavaScript) with server side scripting (PHP).

Comment: I try it here and it does not work. What am I missing?: http://jsfiddle.net/bJvQL/

Comment: There was capital U in there :) Dude, start looking up documentations. Your know, RTFM :)

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
<style>
#input, #out { 
  width:400px; height:200px;
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid;
  overflow:auto;
}
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#input').on('keydown', function () {
        $('#out').html($('#input').html());
    });
});
</script>

<div id="input" contenteditable="true"> </div>
<div id="out"> </div>
```

Comment: If you have a simple need avoid to load jQuery use javascript.